# Will this cause a memory leak in Go?

Tags: memory-leaks, go, slice

In the following code I have two struct types: `ObjectDefinition` and `fieldDefinition` both in the same package. `fieldDefinition` structs should only be created via a method on `ObjectDefinition` to prevent orphaned fields (the system in question will be an extensible CRM).

The `AddReferenceField` method should create a new `fieldDefintion`, set some variables on it, add it to the parent struct's slice of `*fieldDefinition` and then also return the pointer to it to allow the programmer to easily manipulate the field further without having to find and retrieve it from the slice.

```
type ObjectDefinition struct {
    myId        id.ID
    orgId       id.ID
    apiName     string
    label       string
    pluralLabel string
    description string
    helpText    string
    fields      map[id.ID]*fieldDefinition
    newFields   []*fieldDefinition
    systemFields
}

/*
AddReferenceField adds a reference type field to the list of uncommitted fields
with the given parameters and returns a pointer to it. This function will return
a nil pointer and an error if any of the given parameters were invalid.
*/
func (o *ObjectDefinition) AddReferenceField(name, label string, refObj id.ID, reparentable bool, delCon deleteConstraint) (*fieldDefinition, error) {

    //TODO - investigate this as a possible source of memory leakage. Creating a pointer, adding that pointer to a slice, then returning the same pointer.
    nrf := new(fieldDefinition)
    nrf.fieldType = FT_REFERENCE

    if err := nrf.SetName(name); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := nrf.SetLabel(label); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := nrf.SetReferenceObjectId(refObj); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := nrf.SetReparentable(reparentable); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := nrf.SetDeleteConstraint(delCon); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    o.newFields = append(o.newFields, nrf)
    return nrf, nil

}
```

I haven't included the full `fieldDefinition` code because it's not really relevant and it's quite bulky, but an example of this being used from the main program loop would be:

```
var od ObjectDefinition
newId := id.Generate()
newField, newFieldErr := od.AddReferenceField("example", "Example", newId, false, DC_SETNULL)

newField.SetSomethingElse(true)
```

So now newField is a pointer to `fieldDefinition`, but the same pointer has been added to a slice on `od`. Is there a potential for memory leakage here?

Comment: There are already examples of when the garbage collection misses things. No matter how good it is and how great it makes programming in Go, things like this can still happen: [a tale of two memory leaks](https://vividcortex.com/blog/2014/01/15/two-go-memory-leaks/)

Comment: I don't see a problem here, just holding two pointers to the same object is perfectly fine, and there isn't even a cyclic reference. So why would it cause  a leak? And even if there was, the go GC can detect unreferenced objects with cyclic internal references AFAIK.

Comment: The go garbage collector is fully precise, meaning it doesn't "miss" anything (if it did, that would be a bug).

Comment: In general, the only cause for "memory leaks" in go is hanging goroutines that never exit and hold references to objects.

Comment: Somebody should just give the "No" answer.

Comment: @leylandski, the article you linked shows that the memory never becomes eligible for garbage collection because of logic errors in the code, namely clean-up code that never got ran and goroutines that stayed blocked.  That's a separate issue from the garbage collector missing anything.

Comment: @Volker would that really be in line with the constructive and helpful nature of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go is a [garbage collected language](https://golang.org/doc/faq#garbage_collection). Echoing what people in the comments have said, this does not cause a memory leak.  While `od` holds the pointer to the newly created `fieldDefinition`, that `fieldDefinition` will stay in the heap. When `od` goes out of scope and is destroyed, all the `fieldDefinition`s it's pointing to will also become eligible for garbage collection, provided that nothing live is holding a pointer to them.

Comment: Thank you :) this answer cleared up some doubt and confusion about GC that I had. Pointers and memory management has never been my strong suit.